# Multiple http function and timer function in one function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Hi guys I am new to azure function app we have requirement for having multiple azure function in one function app.I have 1 timer function and multiple http function when a timer trigger in it we are using http function accordingly

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: I want http and timer function in one azure function when I place them in one class it is not working

Comment: Need an idea repo idea to put everything at once and can publish all functions to single function app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but it is recommended to create an individual azure functions in their respective classes of same function app with your required functionalities and then publish the Function app to portal. Below is something how a function app file structure looks like when multiple functions are added.

```
<Function App>
| - bin 
| - <1st Function> 
| | - function.json 
| - <2nd Function> 
| | - function.json 
| - host.json
```

You can add new function to your existing function app by right clicking on your **Function app >> Add >> New Azure Function**.

***STEP - 1:***

[image]

***STEP - 2:*** Select the required function

[image]

Once you have performed the required changes, then you can publish the function App by navigating to your **Function app >> Publish**.

[image]

Function App in my local environment.

[image]

After deployment, In portal -

[image]

However, if you are still looking to add multiple functions in one class, you can refer [Azure Functions In One Function App by Rajkishore - Azure Lessons](https://azurelessons.com/azure-how-many-functions-in-one-function-app/#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20You%20can%20keep%20multiple%20Azure%20Functions%20in,Azure%20Function%20s%20like%20below%20inside%20one%20class.)